# List of nouns by category

Tags: discussion, resources

I would like to find a dictionary book which classifies nouns by category: animals, food, part of body, location, etc.

I found lists on Internet, but they are too small and the number of categories are very limited. Ex: http://www.enchantedlearning.com/wordlist/

A dictionary could offer more specific categories. For example, "car" or "book" (type of book), etc.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a topical dictionary. These were, apparently, [more common in the past](https://books.google.com/books?id=aOe2YaiK_MkC&lpg=PA15&dq=%22topical%20dictionaries%22&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q=%22topical%20dictionaries%22&f=false), before the great advantages of alphabetization were fully understood, but you can still find them in modern times.

One that might work for you is [*Descriptionary: A Thematic Dictionary* by Marc McCutcheon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0816079471). The Amazon review says:

> Rather than the alphabetical arrangement found in dictionaries and thesauruses, the **words here are grouped according to general categories, such as animal and insects, food and drink, the human body and mind, and occupations**. Within these broad areas are subheadings--"environment" has been divided into 30 categories ranging from atmosphere to wind. The word listings in these short sections are alphabetical, and while each has a straightforward explanation, you won't find alternative spellings, a pronunciation guide, or any of those dictionary-standard accompaniments to the definition.

You may also be able to find it through your library; the [WorldCat listing is here](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/1005477094).

Note that this includes words of various types of speech, not just nouns. Also, you would probably want to combine this with a traditional dictionary, for things like pronunciation guides and more extensive definitions that this book lacks.

Some thesauruses are also organized this way; I used to have one called *The Word Finder* that I really liked. It is now out of print, though, and may have been primarily for adjectives and adverbs.

If you have access to the [online version of the Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/)<sup>1</sup>, you can also use this wonderful tool for your purposes:

- From the home page, click on the "Categories" link (just below the main search box) to browse words by subject, usage, region, or origin. This will take you to a page showing the various main categories.

  - Subject categories include things like Arts, Law, Sport & Leisure, and Transport.
  - You can click on one of these, or hovering over them will show you sub-categories; for example, hovering over "Consumables" takes you to "Food and Cooking".
- Once you have clicked on a category or sub-category, you will see a list of results.
- You can narrow these down further by using any of the "Refine your search" options (to the right of the results, on my screen).

  - These include narrowing by Part of Speech as well as things like Language of Origin and Date of First Citation. Click on Part of Speech and select "Nouns".
  - Another very useful refinement is "Usage" which has options like "archaic", "rare", and "colloquial and slang". Not all words have such a usage tag (and I haven't figured out a way to *exclude* certain usages), but if you especially want rare words or insults, this is a great feature.

You can also use the "Advanced Search" feature and pre-select all of these categories, rather than narrowing sequentially.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that the [OED is not the same thing as the Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://public.oed.com/about/the-oed-and-oxford-dictionaries/); the OED Online is a paid subscription service. However, many libraries and institutions of higher learning have subscriptions, so you may be able to access it that way. You can learn more on the [OED's page about library access](http://public.oed.com/about/free-oed/), or ask at your school or local library. If you don't have institutional access, you can [look into subscribing here](http://public.oed.com/how-to-subscribe/).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting on-line is as good as it gets. A normal dictionary will *sometimes* tag nouns with some category like 'military' or 'medical'. But that depends on the dictionary.

A more comprehensive source is [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/). This gives all the relations that a particular word has with other words (both links to synonyms, and qualifying nuances, which are like the categories you're asking about.

Also, a dictionary (and Wordnet) is a reference meaning you start with a word and wonder things about it and go to the dictionary as a resource to explain that single word. I have a feeling you're looking for something slightly different  which is a learning source. You would like to study *all* the words in a given category, for example words for operating a laptop, or words labeling items in an automotive repair shop. That's what the categorized word lists on-line get you and you just have to keep seeking until you find the one you like (or extend them yourself as you find them).